# Bulk import data to mysql without specifying file extension

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to load data from files to MySQL, but the files don't have an extension. How can i load the files without specifying the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), it doesn't require any file extension. You just name your file.

Both of the following would work fine:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'data' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

The command-line equivalent of LOAD DATA INFILE, [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html), says this in its doc:

> For each text file named on the command line, mysqlimport strips any extension from the file name and uses the result to determine the name of the table into which to import the file's contents. For example, files named patient.txt, patient.text, and patient all would be imported into a table named patient.

Comment: Hi @Bill, there are 1000's of file that needs to be imported. I can't  use each file name to import one by one.

Comment: @occasionalvisitor, write a script to loop over the files in a directory.

Answer (score -1):

I believe we can't pass a directory to LOAD DATA INFILE without specifying the complete file name . I did a merge of all the files to a single file and then ingested the data